# trouble in making query in sql to create such join (HUE)

Tags: sql, date, join, left-join, hue

I  want to join these two tables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5yfs.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7oqn.png)

I want to join these table as "Table 1 **left join** Table 2". Such that output looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZtwu.png)

Here we are joining on column "Boat code" (unique code for each boat) first and then "Boat service date" will match to nearest lower "Boat purchase/Ownership change date" for that particular Boat code.

Table1 LEFT JOIN Table2
on Table1.boad_code=table2.boat_code
and table1.Boat_service_date to the nearest lower Boat_purchase/Ownership_change_date

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

I really don't understand the x in your `Boat`. However you'll need to find the nearest date with a subquery and then join the whole result with your `table2`.

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
firstResult.Boat, 
srv_date, 
acq_date, 
`Name`, 
Gender
 FROM 
   (SELECT 
      *,
      (SELECT t2.acq_date FROM table2 t2 WHERE 
    t2.acq_date< t1.`srv_date` ORDER BY t2.acq_date DESC LIMIT 1 )minDate 
       FROM table1 t1
   ) firstResult
JOIN table2 t3 ON t3.`acq_date`=firstResult.minDate
```

Comment: I have to join these tables based on 2 columns on column being boat. Here, i have taken cases of a particular boat code just to clear the requirements.

Comment: Did my query help?

Comment: It is not running

Comment: I have edited the data in the question. Now, it should clear what i want to do. Thanks